# Which is more easier to customize and extend sugarcrm or Vtiger

Tags: php, sugarcrm, vtiger

I am working on a project and we need a support system like crm for own customers. 
Could you please help me which one should I choose

My needs are
1. Can easily be accessed on mobile web
2. I can easily add my own extention
3. cutomize whole user interface according to my needs
4. Most importantly able to sign with different accounts like gmail, facebook, twitter etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SugarCRM has all the framework in place for easy customizations.  Depending on your knowledge of PHP and MySQL you can go even further than the Module Builder/Studio tool that SugarCRM provides in all versions.  SugarCRM provides Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, GoogleDocs, plus many more connectors by default.  Depending on your needs Sugar provides everything from a free Community Edition (which is very functional, but doesn't have reporting functionality) to Enterprise Edition which has the most features, but conversely isn't free.  I've been working with SugarCRM for over a year, and while there is a little bit of a learning curve, but it's not as bad other systems.

Comment: Hi @frosty i am new to opensource crm i need little help in webform please help me i tried both sugarcrm and vtiger crm but having issues on webform did not shown on browser

Answer (score 2):

go for `SugarCRM`
it will cater all your needs

i have worked on this , it is good